# how to fetch facebook page data without asking to do facebook login & just simply verifying associated email address of facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Here this site has implemented that thing which i am asking in my question.

[enter link description here](https://www.gloopla.com/login/start)
Here Flow:

1. End user submit facebook page url
2. Site will check that facebook page url is available or not
3. IF it is available then it will display associated email id & ask use to confirm it & inform to verify that email by clicking on link which they will send on that email address.
4. Once user verify that email address by clicking on link , site will fetch facebook page data .

Here there is no facebook login flow & applications permission or token access involve .

How to achieve this kind of setup. What are the way or resource may i need to study ?

Comment: Which associated mail you are looking for ? Friends email address ?

Comment: No. its mail address which entered into facebook page while creating facebook page.

Comment: Do you have any facebook page ?if yes then please can you follow  above steps into this site : https://www.gloopla.com/login/start

Comment: Without any Facebook login, they can only be using Page Public Content Access, most likely with an app access token. So they will only get fully public/ non-targeted posts in the first place.

Comment: @Vaghasiyakrunal Hi tried with my fb account amit.choudhary966 and what it saying is "The specified page was not found on Facebook. Please try again." . I think if user has made public availability ON then can fetch by this only.

Comment: @amku91 Hi. There is difference between user account & page. You tried with user account. that's why it's saying page was not found on facebook .

Comment: @CBroe I think you are right. Just get to know about  Page Public Content Access feature. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS     I think i have to submit application with this permission right ? after that, i can get any other facebook page data as like gloopla.com/login/start   & implement this kind of setup. Am I right ?

Comment: Basically, yes. Whether Facebook will approve that feature for such a use case - not sure, you’d have to give it a try.

Comment: @CBore   Here  is problem with public content access permission.  I have try it before applying for app review ,i have to test & show into screencast as per fb official document . but problem is that i cloud not test .

Comment: they said that While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app. I am trying to do it butt getting error. To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook  .. here is bug reported: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2139350026277360/?disable_redirect=0  .. here i have my fb page admin role & app admin role too.